# mysql optimize consult Join

Tags: mysql, join, optimization

can anyone help me...
I'm learning ajax, php and mysql. and I'm trying to do a query to multiple tables to form together a price list according to brand, to update.

what I have done, it is a query that is not optimized, and that is what I want, me and help me explain the use of "join".

**Structure:**

```
Table 1
+------------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+
|    ID      |  Pro_Cod  |  ActProf   |     mark   |  status    |
+------------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+
|   1        |  00003    |       1    |  002       |      1     |
+------------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+
|   2        |  00033    |       1    |  002       |      1     |
+------------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+
|   3        |  00034    |       2    |  023       |      1     |
+------------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+
|   4        |  00036    |       2    |  009       |      0     |
+------------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+

Table 2
+------------+----------+------------+------------+
|    ID      |  Pro_Cod |  ActProf   |  Name      |
+------------+----------+------------+------------+
|   1        |  00003   |       1    |  product 1 |
+------------+----------+------------+------------+
|   2        |  00033   |       1    |  product 2 |
+------------+----------+------------+------------+
|   3        |  00034   |       2    |  product 3 |
+------------+----------+------------+------------+
|   4        |  00036   |       2    |  product 4 |
+------------+----------+------------+------------+

Table 3
+------------+----------+------------+------------+
|       ID   |  Pro_Cod |  ActProf   |  Price     |
+------------+----------+------------+------------+
|       1    |  00003   |       1    |  10.00     |
+------------+----------+------------+------------+
|       2    |  00033   |       1    |  15.00     |
+------------+----------+------------+------------+
|       3    |  00034   |       2    |  13.00     |
+------------+----------+------------+------------+
|       4    |  00036   |       2    |  14.00     |
+------------+----------+------------+------------+
```

**Code:**
Explanation: Table 1 Filter of products that are active (status = 1), and are of a single brand (mark = $ var), seek and obtain the data of Table 2 and 3, from the results of Table 1 filter.

**print data:**
Product code, name, price and input update.

```
$ListArray  ='';
        $c=1;#Counter
        #Query 
        $stmtpre    =   "SELECT  Prod_Code , Prod_PF FROM  Avipac_MasterProducts  WHERE Prod_ST=0 AND Prod_Mark='".$s_list_100."';";
        #Consult
        $data       =   $this   ->  DBMANAGER   ->  BDquery($stmtpre, DBPRODUCT);
        #Cicle + Array
        while ($row1    =   mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)){
            #more need data:
            $stmtpre    =   "SELECT   Prod_NameL  FROM  Avipac_Prod_Profile WHERE Prod_Code=".$row1['Prod_Code']." AND Prod_PF='".$row1['Prod_PF']."';";
            $data1      =   $this   ->  DBMANAGER   ->  BDquery($stmtpre, DBPRODUCT);
            $datar      =   $this   ->  DBMANAGER   ->  BDassoc($data1);

            $stmtpre    =   "SELECT  Prod_D_5 FROM  Avipac_Prod_Det_Cost WHERE Prod_Code=".$row1['Prod_Code']." AND Prod_PF='".$row1['Prod_PF']."';";
            $data2      =   $this   ->  DBMANAGER   ->  BDquery($stmtpre, DBPRODUCT);
            $datap      =   $this   ->  DBMANAGER   ->  BDassoc($data2);

            $ListArray  .='<div class="col-md-2 has-warning"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="i_txt_1_'.$c.'" value="'.$row1['Prod_Code'].'" required readonly></div>';
            $c++;
            $ListArray  .='<div class="col-md-6 has-warning"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="i_txt_2_'.$c.'" value="'.$datar['Prod_NameL'].'" required readonly></div>';
            $c++;
            $ListArray  .='<div class="col-md-2 has-warning"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="i_txt_3_'.$c.'" value="'.$datap['Prod_D_5'].'" required readonly></div>';
            $c++;
            $ListArray  .='<div class="col-md-2 has-warning"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="i_txt_4_'.$c.'" value="'.$datap['Prod_D_5'].'"></div>';
            $c=1;
        }
        return $ListArray;
```

Comment: Your data does not seem to be _normalized_, meaning the same set of columns (well, almost the same) appear in all three tables.

Comment: what you say is true, each table has different data, they are related by product code only. and wanted to know if the query can be optimized more. update produc code is the same.

Comment: It might be helpful if you also show us what output you expect from the query.

Comment: ok, if you look at the code, the output would be the product id, detail and price.

as I apply the filter brand, if I choose the 002 should only show the first two and the only product that should not be displayed is # 4, and that is inactive.
Product # 3 does not meet the condition that either mark is displayed.

Comment: the question is, can optimize the query 2 and 3 merging them into one ?? to make the system faster and more efficient?

Comment: You need `INDEX(status, mark)`

Comment: ok thank but i have it on the structure of database, i need implement it on query string??? as it would be?